# Creating Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to create a very simple trigger and am getting the error:
Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure trig_UpdateTransferBools, Line 1
The object 'dbo.DW_WEEK_RANGE' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

The table clearly exists; I created it!
Could this be a permissions issue at all?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trig_UpdateTransferBools ON [dbo.DW_WEEK_RANGE]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT Transfer FROM dbo.DW_WEEK_RANGE WHERE Module = 'PURCHASES') = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo.DW_WEEK_RANGE] SET Transfer = 0 WHERE Module = 'SALES'
            UPDATE [dbo.DW_WEEK_RANGE] SET Transfer = 0 WHERE Module = 'RETAIL SALES'
        END

END
```

Comment: Are you sure it's created in the dbo context ? Can we see a screenshot of your database ?

Answer (score 1):

It has to be `dbo.[DW_WEEK_RANGE]` or `[dbo].[DW_WEEK_RANGE]` not `[dbo.DW_WEEK_RANGE]`

schema.table

you can also leave out the brackets, the brackets are there so that you can name tables something silly like a blank space or a keyword

example

```
CREATE TABLE [ ](id INT)

INSERT [ ] VALUES(1)

SELECT * FROM [ ]
```

Comment: Well you know the answer to everything is 42  :-)